# Windows Apache SSL Configuration not loading page

Tags: windows, apache, ssl

I am trying to configure Apache SSL on Windows for the first time and I am having some configuration nightmare. 
Here is how I generated a crt and key file for a wildcard certificate:

copied openssl.cnf file to Apache24/bin directory and issued the following commands:

```
openssl req -config openssl.cnf -new -out mycooldomain.csr -keyout mycooldomain.pem
```

For the common name, I entered *.mycooldomain.com
This generated me the .pem file

Then next command to give me .key file

```
openssl rsa -in mycooldomain.pem -out mycooldomain.key
```

The following command generates the .crt file

```
openssl x509 -sha512 -in mycooldomain.csr -out mycooldomain.crt -req -signkey mycooldomain.key -days 3650
```

Now I enabled mod_ssl in httpd.conf by removing # in front of it

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
```

I double clicked on crt file to install it in Trusted Root CA and it installed successfully

Here is my virtualhost configurations:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443>
    ServerAdmin name@mycooldomain.org
    DocumentRoot "C:\htdocs\coolsites\upgrade"
    ServerName upgrade.mycooldomain.com:443 
    ErrorLog "C:\Apache24\logs\upgrade-mycooldomain-com-error_log"
    CustomLog "C:\Apache24\logs\upgrade-mycooldomain-com-access_log" common
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "C:/Apache24/conf/certificates/mycooldomain.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/Apache24/conf/certificates/mycooldomain.key"      

     <Directory "C:\htdocs\coolsites\upgrade">  
        RewriteEngine On                
        Allow From All  
     </Directory>   
</VirtualHost>
```

restarted the apache service afterwords

I also checked the firewall for port 443. Since it is local server, Apache is allowed on all tcp and udp ports.

When I try to load the site https://upgrade.mycooldomain.com it just say that it can't load the siite
Any help regarding this is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried on port 80, to first ensure all is well without the certificates?  Then put your LogLevel to debug, you might see some message.  BTW wildcard certificates are ok for dev, but more and more browsers now reject them so you could have problems there as well.

Comment: I been using port 80 from almost two months and site is working fine on port 80.It is just that I need to make it https now. I am using wildcard certificate only for the development since I have around four virtual hosts with the same domain but different subdomain. Instead of creating individual certs, I thought wildcard certificate would be a better idea

Comment: In a recent upgrade of Chrome, they block wildcard certificates.  I had to put new certificates on all our dev at work.  But that might not be the problem here, just letting you know.

Comment: I can certainly generate certificate individually for each site. But it shouldn't refuse the connection. When I don't have certificate or an invalid certificate, it should complain about it.

Comment: Is there a `Listen *:443` directive anywhere?  Is port 443 in LISTEN  `(netstat -an|grep 443)`?